# How do you use url_for if content is saved as HTML in a database for Flask / Jinja?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am building a CMS using Flask and storing my HTML content in a database. I can't figure out how to link to internal content. Normally I would use url_for in the template, but if the content is saved in the database this won't work.

Currently everything except for the url_for link is working on my page. In my template I am using the safe filter:

```
{{ about.content|safe }}
```

If I wanted to include a link like the below but the content is stored on a database what can I do?

```
<p><a href="{{ url_for('contact') }}">Send me an email</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware this is not possible.
Jinja2 renders template only at compile time, in other words it downloads contents of database and doesnt bother to interpret whether it means something or not.